# How to save coordinates to Firebase Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to save a set of latitude and longitude coordinates to Firebase, but whenever my app runs through this code it crashes!

```
let userID: String = (FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)!
let lat: Double = (locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!
let lon: Double = (locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude)!

self.ref.child("Location").child(userID).setValue(["Latitude": lat, "Longitude": lon])
```

Is there anyway I can fix this and save it properly and efficiently?

Comment: What kind of crash do you get? 
Maybe you get nil somewhere in the right side of assigning in the first 3 lines of code? You have force unwrap operator, and it may crash in runtime if the value getting unwrapped is nil

Comment: Are your core location delegate methods being called?

Comment: @Dravidian yea they are being called. But my app crashes and shows me that it stops right when I have created the let variable lat.

Comment: I have given a detailed answer , Try that , if any issues just let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure of two things :-

1.) your viewController inherits from `CLLocationManagerDelegate` and has its `delegate` set to self in `viewDidLoad`

2.) your `info.plist` has these keys added to them :-

NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription --- I need Location

NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription --- I need Location

privacy - location usage description --- I need Location

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController , CLLocationManagerDelegate...{

...
..

let locationManager   = CLLocationManager()

func viewDidLoad(){
  super.viewDidLoad()

    locationManager.delegate = self

    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

   }

//Call these functions for updating the getting the values of current  location


   func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {


    if status == .AuthorizedWhenInUse {


        print("authorised call came . . . . ")
        mapView.myLocationEnabled = true

    }
}




func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    if let location = locations.first {

    print("target position : =  \(location.coordinate)")
    print(locationManager.location!.coordinate.latitude)
    mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: location.coordinate, zoom: 15, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    self.FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Location").child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid).setValue(["Latitude": locationManager.location!.coordinate.latitude, "Longitude": locationManager.location!.coordinate.longitude])
    }

}

 }
```